# prevent bslib card_title resize

Tags: shiny, card, bslib

i used to be a big fan of the `shinydashboardPlus dashboardPage`, with its right sidebar, but recently learned about `bslib` and am trying to recreate the functionality here.  i've somewhat got the sidebars down (would like the right sidebar to not squish body contents but instead just cover over), but i'm really struggling with the title.  i want it to be a fixed size like the header and footer, and for reasons i'm interested in having a header and title both.  the documentation for `card_title` doesn't show any arguments for height or filling, but i tried using the same parameters that `card_body` has available.  none of them seemed to do the trick, any ideas?  for learning purposes, i'm interested in avoiding random bits of css added to my code, and would also like to figure out how this works with `page_fillable` (vice `page_navbar` which has a title bar and can have sidebars).  thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_fillable(
    
    title = "Page Fillable Template",
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "pulse"),
    fillable_mobile = TRUE,  #narrow windows
    
    card(
        card_title(
            "this is the title, i don't want it to resize with sidebar collapse or to be sized too tall"
        ),
        card_header(
            "This is the header, its size stays fixed... me likey"
        ),
        card_body(
            padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #makes the left sidebar flush with its container
            
            #left sidebar widget
            layout_sidebar(
                padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #makes the right sidebar flush with its container
                
                #left sidebar contents
                sidebar = sidebar(
                    width = 400,
                    position = "left",
                    open = "open",
                    
                    p("left sidebar contents, will be an assortment of input widgets"),
                    p("if really tall, the contents shrink the height of the title above, up to some minimum, and then the sidebar will have a scrollbar, which i'm fine with"),
                    p("but maybe instead of a scroll bar, i'd like the entire app to scroll down, but then i guess i wouldn't use a page_fillable"),
                    p("anyways, when sufficiently filled with content, the title above squishes down nicely and looks good"),
                    p("however, when i collapse the sidebar, then the title above expands to fill half the vertical space of the app")
                ),
                
                #right sidebar widget
                layout_sidebar(
                    
                    #right sidebar contents
                    sidebar = sidebar(
                        
                        width = 800,
                        position = "right",
                        open = "closed",
                        
                        #sidebar contents
                        p("right sidebar contents, can this sidebar open without squishing the main panel content, instead just covering it up until closed, as if the content here is just a reference to peek at periodically and then keep hidden usually?")
                    ),
                    
                    #main contents
                    layout_columns(
                        # gap = 25,
                        # padding = c(25, 25, 25, 25),
                        
                        col_widths = breakpoints(
                            sm = c(12, 12, 12),    #3 rows, 12 wide
                            md = c(6, 6, 12),      #2 rows, 6+6 and 12
                            lg = c(4, 4, 4)        #1 row,  4+4+4
                        ),
                        
                        p("contents 1"),
                        p("contents 2"),
                        p("contents 3")
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        card_footer(
            "This is the footer, its size stays fixed... me likey"
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    bs_themer()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

a solution... referenced in my comment:

```
ui <- page_fillable(
    
    title = "Page Fillable Template",
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "pulse"),
    
    fillable_mobile = TRUE,  #narrow windows
    padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #app container flush in browser window
    
    card(
        card_header(
            "header as header"
        ),
        
        card_body(
            padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #right sidebar flush
            
            layout_sidebar(
                padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #nested container for additional sidebar flush
                
                #right sidebar
                sidebar = sidebar(
                    
                    width = 800,
                    position = "right",
                    open = "closed",     #"desktop", "open", "closed", "always"
                    
                    p("right sidebar contents, can this sidebar open without squishing the main panel content, instead just covering it up until closed, as if the content here is just a reference to peek at periodically and then keep hidden usually?")
                ),
                
                card(
                    card_header(
                        "Header as Title",
                        container = htmltools::h1
                    ),
                    
                    card_body(
                        padding = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  #left sidebar flush
                        
                        layout_sidebar(
                            
                            #left sidebar
                            sidebar = sidebar(
                                
                                width = 400,
                                position = "left",
                                open = "open",      #"desktop", "open", "closed", "always"
                                
                                p("left sidebar contents, will be an assortment of input widgets")
                            ),
                            
                            #main contents
                            layout_columns(
                                col_widths = breakpoints(
                                    sm = c(12, 12, 12),    #3 rows, 12 wide
                                    md = c(6, 6, 12),      #2 rows, 6+6 and 12
                                    lg = c(4, 4, 4)        #1 row,  4+4+4
                                ),
                                
                                p("contents 1"),
                                p("contents 2"),
                                p("contents 3")
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        card_footer(
            "footer"
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    bs_themer()
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: this works, but i'd still like to know how to adjust the behavior of card_title perhaps.  i'd also really like to know if that right sidebar can be made to overlap the body contents rather than squish it.  thanks!